# odoo-8 Template 'report.layout' not found

Tags: odoo-8

I can't print no reports anymore with odoo 8.

As it seems, the error is in the database because a newly created database doesn't have this problem.

But how can I correct this in the current database?

```
File "/opt/odoo8/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 200, in get_template    
raise QWebTemplateNotFound("Template %r not found" % name, template=origin_template)
QWebTemplateNotFound: Template 'report.layout' not found
```

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 2):

You probably have mistakenly butchered either web.layout or report.layout records. In your database that works. Go to Settings -> User Interface -> Views and search for layout. Select report.layout and make note of the configuration and values. Export it or copy it to your broken database. Your broken database may be missing this record entirely. This is a base view so unless you have modified it a vanilla record should work. The important part is the external id as without it you will probable still get this error.